# To control canvas object position with range inputs

Tags: canvas, slider, range

I am able to move the object horizontal using the range slider input.  I am able to move the object vertical using the range slider input.  I am using the variable cx (circle X) and cy (circle Y) to log the X, Y position of the circle, this functions as require for the axis being adjusted but the other axis always reverts to 150 i.e. var cx = 150.  meaning the variable cx is not updating value.

the JS used is:

```
$(function(){

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth=6;
ctx.strokeStyle='green';

var PI2=Math.PI*2; //place the circle on canvas
var cx = 150; //these are the initial value but not updated when moved?
var cy = 150;
var radius=3;
drawX(0);
drawY(0);



var $xpos=$('#xpos');
$xpos.on('change',function(){
    drawX(parseInt($xpos.val()));
    console.log("hori: " +xpos);
});

var $ypos=$('#ypos');
$ypos.on('change',function(){
    drawY(parseInt($ypos.val()));
    console.log("vert: " +ypos);
});

function drawX(x){

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx+x,cy,radius,0,PI2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    console.log("Y axis: " + cy);
    console.log("Y axis: " + cy);
}

function drawY(y){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy+y,radius,0,PI2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    console.log("X axis: " +cx);
    console.log("X axis: " +cy);
}
```

});

the controls are simple range input sliders applied to a canvas object:

```
     <label>X-pos<input type=range id=xpos min=-170 value=0 max=170 step=1></label><br>
<label>Y-pos<input type=range id=ypos min=-170 value=0 max=170 step=1></label><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because both your functions are called `draw()`.

You can only declare one function with one name so the both your sliders will call for the same function and move the rectangle in the same direction.

You need to give them unique names. Try `drawX()` and `drawY()`.

Comment: Upvote for catching the problem. You might also be DRY and combine the 2 draw functions into a single draw function with a signature like: `function draw(x,y)` where you can supply 0 for the x or y you don't wish to change. ;-)